# Which specific Scripture of the Law are the people referring to in John 12:34?

Tags: law, christology

John 12:34:- … “We have heard from the law that the Christ remains forever; …”

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:** It doesn't say exactly.

---

However, they are probably referencing excerpts from the Hebrew Scriptures, commonly known as the Old Testament, that describe the everlasting nature of the Messiah or the perpetual nature of his kingdom.

For example:

> 2 Samuel 7:16 NKJV
>
> 16 And your house and your kingdom shall be established forever before
> you. Your throne shall be established forever.

This verse’s promise is often understood as Messianic, pointing towards the eternal reign of the Messiah, who is seen as the fulfillment of the Davidic covenant.

Another example is:

> Psalm 89:36-37 NKJV
>
> 36 His seed shall endure forever, And his throne as the sun before Me;
> 37 It shall be established forever like the moon, Even like the
> faithful witness in the sky.” Selah

This verse speaks of the perpetual nature of God's covenant with David.

These passages, among others, likely formed the basis of the people's understanding that the Messiah, when he comes, will remain forever.

Other verses include: Isaiah 9:6-7, Daniel 7:13-14, Micah 5:2, Psalm 110:1-4

**My conclusion** then is that this statement made by individuals in John 12:34, "We have heard from *the law* that the Christ remains forever," indicates an expectation within Jewish tradition about the eternal characteristics of the Messiah and his kingdom. Although the text does not specify which verses from the Law they are referencing, various passages in the Hebrew Scriptures suggest the concept of the Messiah's perpetual reign and his permanent kingdom.

Comment: thanks; upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

First, note the comment of Ellicott -

> (34) we have heard out of the law that Christ abideth for ever.. . . .
> .—The term “law” refers to the whole of the Old Testament Scripture,
> as we have seen in John 10:34. (Comp. Note there.)

This is important because, it is unlikely that the Jews referred to anything in the Torah.  However, "law" could and often refers to what we now call the entire Old Testament.

The comment of the Jews that (John 12:34) … “*We have heard from the law that the Christ remains forever; …*” could refer to any of the following passages:

- Ps 89:29 - I will establish his line forever, his throne as long as the heavens endure.
- Ps 89:36 - his offspring shall endure forever, and his throne before Me like the sun
- Ps 72:5 - May they fear him as long as the sun shines, as long as the moon remains through all generations.
- Ps 72:17 - May his name endure forever; may his name continue as long as the sun shines. In him may all nations be blessed; may they call him blessed.
- Ps 110:4 - The LORD has sworn and will not change His mind: “You are a priest forever in the order of Melchizedek.”
- Isa 9:6, 7 - For unto us a child is born, unto us a son is given, and the government will be upon His shoulders. And He will be called Wonderful Counselor, Mighty God, Everlasting Father, Prince of Peace. Of the increase of His government and peace there will be no end. He will reign on the throne of David and over his kingdom, to establish and sustain it with justice and righteousness from that time and forevermore. The zeal of the LORD of Hosts will accomplish this.
- Eze 37:25 - They will live in the land that I gave to My servant Jacob, where your fathers lived. They will live there forever with their children and grandchildren, and My servant David will be their prince forever.
- Dan 7:14 - “And to Him was given dominion, Glory and a kingdom, That all the peoples, nations and men of every language Might serve Him. His dominion is an everlasting dominion Which will not pass away; And His kingdom is one Which will not be destroyed.

There are many more that could be quoted that all point to the coming messianic kingdom as enduring forever.

Comment: +1. As always, very nice and comprehensive!

Answer (score 1):

The problem (for those who had heard from the law that the Christ remains forever) was that they had just heard Jesus say that he would be "lifted up". They rightly understood that that mean, lifted up to die.

So, had they heard correctly, and understood from the reading of the law? Note that in John 10:34 the Psalms are included in the law, also in John 15:25. Here is a commentary on John 12:34:

> "We have heard = we heard. The Gk. tense (aorist) refers to a definite
> time, and may refer to a portion of the law read on the Great Sabbath
> two days previously. The quotation is usually referred to Psalm 89:29,
> but it may rather be Psalm 92 which is said to have been read on the
> Sabbath from the days of Ezra." *The Companion Bible*, p.15551,
> Bullinger, 1974 reprint

There's too much in those two Psalms to quote here, to show the various places where this living forever could be interpreted to apply to the promised Messiah. However, here is another quotation referring to misunderstanding some of the prophecies about Messiah:

> "The word quoted in John 12:38-40, afore given to Isaiah in prophecy
> when the vision of the Lord was revealed, in the book of the prophet
> appears to be a reference to Isaiah's contemporary ministry. But this
> is not the case in fact. John assures us that both vision and speech
> in reality apply to the ministry of Christ, John 12:41.
>
> The words are a prophecy concerning the effect upon the Jews of the
> person and public ministry not of Isaiah but of Jesus: 'That the
> saying of Esaias the prophet might be fulfilled.' John 12:37-41. This
> shows indisputably that Esaias the prophet foretold of Jesus, saw him
> in vision, heard his words, and spake of him and his ministry...
> Moreover in John 12:39 the apostle John states categorically of Jesus'
> ministry, 'Therefore they' - the Jews - 'could not believe' - in
> Christ...
>
> However, the Jews thought all that [Jesus] had said foolishness, being
> confused and confounded by the very religion which they had imbibed.
> 'We have heard out of the law that Christ abideth for ever.' But this
> contention implies that their own conscience witnessed to them that he
> was the Christ. Hence on that ground they objected to his saying that
> he would be lifted up. How they contradict themselves!
>
> Evidently they understood enough to grasp that 'lifted up' meant
> lifted up to die. But, to them, Christ would never die. What
> perplexity of mind possessed thee Jews! Whichever way they turned,
> something out of their law denied the turning. As to the Son of man,
> Who was he? What, asking *this,* after so long a time?
>
> ...Yet before their very eyes the Light of the world shone. But the
> light did not penetrate. Nor had they long. Soon he would be gone.
> Hence he saith, 'Yet a little while is the light with you. Walk while
> ye have the light, lest darkness come upon you: for he that walketh in
> darkness knowesth not whither he goeth." John Chapters 1 to 12 The
> First Six Signs, John Metcalfe, pp.486-7 then p. 482,
> http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

Answer (score 0):

The verse that prophesied the coming of Jesus Christ and this verse was mistakenly interpreted to mean that he was going to be an earthly king. The verse says that there will be no end to his Messianic Kingdom.

**Isaiah 9:7**

> Of the increase of his government and of peace there will be no end, on the throne of David and over his kingdom, to establish it and to uphold it with justice and with righteousness from this time forth and forevermore.